# How to finish a letter in a conciliatory manner

Tags: expressions, formality

I have drafted a letter to someone who works in the same team as me, discussing some issues regarding teamworking and I want to finish the letter by saying that I hope they receive the letter in a conciliatory spirit, as it is intended. Is there a good formal way I can put that?

Comment: I think this is a request for *writing advice* (effectively, Off Topic, primarily opinion-based).

Comment: Agree FumbkeFingers - it's asking people to invent something the OP should come up with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for writing advice.

Comment: I've submitted an edit rephrasing this to avoid the OT issue.  There's some value as a letter-closing word choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you've discussed it's difficult to suggest a phrase. So....say what you mean (assuming you mean it) eg. "I hope my comments are understood in the constructive way I hope I've described them, and look forward to working together positively blah blah in the future"